# Using whereRelation with a subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have wrote a zip_code query that I am wanting to add to another query. The problem is I am not exactly sure how to combine these via whereRelation().

```
$zip_code = ZipCode::where('office', '=', function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('office')->from('zip_codes')->where('zip_code', session()->get('zip_code'));
    })->get();

$appointment = Appointment::with('customer', 'blocks', 'status', 'services.service')->whereRelation('customer', 'zip_code', $zip_code)->get();
```

The output of `$appointment` is:

```
select * from appointments where exists (select * from customers where appointments.customer_id = customers.id and zip_code = {"id":1,"zip_code":00000,"city":"City","office":"LOCATION"})
```

`$zip_code` is returning this query. I am just wanting those results to be called in the `whereRelation()` so all the zip_codes for that office are returned:

```
SELECT * FROM zip_codes 

where office = (
    
    select office 
    from zip_codes
    where zip_code = '00000'
    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pluck the zip_code values from the $zip_code collection like so.

```php
$zip_code = ZipCode::select('zip_code')
    ->where(
        'office',
        function($query) {
            $query->select('office')
                ->from('zip_codes')
                ->where(
                    'zip_code',
                    session()->get('zip_code')
                );
        }
    )->get();

$zip_code = $zip_code->pluck('zip_code')->all();
```

Then use that in the next query for filtering the relation.

```php
$appointment = Appointment::with('customer', 'blocks', 'status', 'services.service')
    ->whereRelation(
        'customer', 
        function($query) {
            $query->whereIn('zip_code', $zip_code);
        }
    )->get();
```

Otherwise, you could query for the office with the given zip code, carry out a join of the customer and the zip codes table then filter out customers with zip codes pertaining to the office.

```php
$offices = ZipCode::select('office')
    ->where('zip_code', session()->get('zip_code'))
    ->get();
$offices = $offices->pluck('office')->all();

$appointment = Appointment::with(
    'customer',
    'blocks',
    'status',
    'services.service'
)->whereHas('customer', function ($query) {
    $query->join('zip_codes', function ($join) {
        $join->on('zip_codes.zip_code', 'customers.zip_code');
        $join->whereIn('zip_codes.office', $office);
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error that customers cannot be found. the customers table is coming from the 'customer' eloquent model.

Comment: @Lynx I only noticed that `EloquentModel::with` eager loads the relationship and thus it is only compiled afterwards on field access. You can use the `EloquentModel::whereHas` method instead and set the join on the query builder instance for the relation

Comment: I gave this another look and infered that the customers table has a zip_code field, let me know if that inference is wrong. You dont really need a join to the zip_codes table if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help think it out. So basically the customer enters their zip code and then they get a schedule to pick a date. But that schedule needs to include all the zip_codes that are part of a "office" field. So one office may have 100 zip_codes so if the customer has one of those zip codes then it looks for the office to show the schedule for that office thus all those zip codes.